# Check whether a table exists in database using python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to check if a table is empty. How do I fetch this info and check if the table has any data in it?

here is what I have done so fat

import mysql.connector

```
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="xxxx",
        database="schedule"
    )
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    table_check=mydb.cursor()


    table_check.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM courses")
    mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

    table_result=table_check.fetchall()

    print(table_result)

    tuples = mycursor.description
    if not tuples:
        print("tuples is empty")
    else:
        print("there are tuples")
```

I would like to know if the "courses" table is empty.

Comment: *"Check whether a table exists in database using python and MySQL"* Research `information_schema.TABLES`  makes it much more easy..

Comment: *"I'm trying to check if a table is empty."* . `SELECT 1 FROM courses LIMIT 1` should be much faster to check if a table is empty or not..